# start quartz timer immediately and then every 1 minute

Tags: timer, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I want to start quartz timer in camel immediately route starts and then after every 1 minute.

I have written cron expression that will run after every minute.

cron expression = 0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *

can anybody suggest how can i fire job immediately and then evry 1 minute?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just define a cron expression for every minute and add the fireNow=true parameter. See http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html.

Comment: thanks @soilworker but still it's not starting immediately

 my camel route from config


<from uri="quartz2://callEndpoint?fireNow=true&amp;cron=0+0/1+*+1/1+*+?+*"/>

it's still not calling immediately.

Comment: K, the fireNow option only works if you use SimpleTrigger, so you can't use the cronExpression for this option. Maybe you should replace the cronExpression with trigger.repeatCount and trigger.repeatInterval or dont use the quartz component. Maybe the timer component is the better choice for you(see http://camel.apache.org/timer.html)